# How do I run a maven plugin's integration tests?

Tags: maven, integration-testing, maven-plugin

I've generated a maven plugin project using the `maven-archetype-plugin` archetype.

I've altered the generated integration test `src/it/simple-it/verify.groovy`  to fail:

```
    assert false
```

I then invoked:

`$ mvn clean install invoker:integration-test invoker:verify`

And my `assert false` test passed:

```
[INFO] Installing /home/peter/ownCloud/Personal/eclipse-workspace/my-plugin/target/my-plugin-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar to /home/peter/.m2/repository/org/example/my-plugin/1.0-SNAPSHOT/my-plugin-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
[INFO] Installing /home/peter/ownCloud/Personal/eclipse-workspace/my-plugin/pom.xml to /home/peter/.m2/repository/org/example/my-plugin/1.0-SNAPSHOT/my-plugin-1.0-SNAPSHOT.pom
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-invoker-plugin:3.1.0:integration-test (default-cli) @ my-plugin ---
[INFO] Building: simple-it/pom.xml
[INFO]           simple-it/pom.xml ................................ SUCCESS (13.4 s)
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-invoker-plugin:3.1.0:verify (default-cli) @ my-plugin ---
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Build Summary:
[INFO]   Passed: 1, Failed: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 34.975 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2019-03-03T08:23:34-04:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 38M/441M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Clearly the test wasn't actually invoked. What am I missing?

To demonstrate the issue, I've created a simple shell script:

```
#!/bin/bash

rm -rf my-plugin
mvn archetype:generate -DgroupId=org.example -DartifactId=my-plugin -DarchetypeArtifactId=maven-archetype-plugin -DarchetypeVersion=1.4 -DinteractiveMode=false
cd my-plugin
echo assert false > src/it/simple-it/verify.groovy
mvn clean install invoker:integration-test invoker:verify
```

I believe that this script should fail on the last line, when the invoker:verify goal is reached, and maven executes `verify.groovy` which is literally an `assert false`.

Comment: Hi, is your test class placed in src/test/java? this could be the reason why the test is not executed.

Comment: Best would be to show your whole project somewhere...

Comment: @khmarbaise Rather than attaching a whole codebase to this question, I've added a shell script that will generate enough of a codebase to demonstrate the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The archetype generator is creating a separate profile for integration tests which is disabled by default.  You will need to enable this profile by running:

```
mvn clean verify -Prun-its
```

Then your test will fail.

You can modify your POM to enable this profile by default by adding the following:

```
<activation>
    <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
</activation>
```

The full profiles block would then be:

```
<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>run-its</id>
        <activation>
            <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
        </activation>
        <build>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-invoker-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.1.0</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <debug>true</debug>
                        <cloneProjectsTo>${project.build.directory}/it</cloneProjectsTo>
                        <pomIncludes>
                            <pomInclude>*/pom.xml</pomInclude>
                        </pomIncludes>
                        <postBuildHookScript>verify</postBuildHookScript>
                        <localRepositoryPath>${project.build.directory}/local-repo</localRepositoryPath>
                        <settingsFile>src/it/settings.xml</settingsFile>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>clean</goal>
                            <goal>test-compile</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </configuration>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <id>integration-test</id>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>install</goal>
                                <goal>integration-test</goal>
                                <goal>verify</goal>
                            </goals>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>
    </profile>
</profiles>
```

At this point you will only need to run:

```
mvn clean verify
```

and it will also fail since the IT tests are now run by default.

For more information about Maven build profiles have a look [Here](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-profiles.html).