# Removing integration-test goal from org.apache.maven.archetype execution

Tags: maven-plugin, jbpm, maven-archetype

I am trying to build JBPM from its source code. I am doing a maven build with skipTests=true.  I believe it is failing because the maven archetype plugin is generating files during "integration-test"

```
[WARNING] Contents of file src\main\resources\rules.drl are not equal
[WARNING] Contents of file src\test\java\it\pkg\RuleTest.java are not equal
[WARNING] Contents of file src\test\resources\log4j.properties are not equal
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Reactor Summary for KIE :: API Parent 7.39.0.Final-redhat-00007:
[INFO]
[INFO] KIE :: API Parent .................................. SUCCESS [  8.784 s]
[INFO] KIE :: Public API .................................. SUCCESS [ 48.164 s]
[INFO] KIE :: Internal .................................... SUCCESS [ 34.910 s]
[INFO] KIE :: Maven Archetypes ............................ SUCCESS [  0.175 s]
[INFO] KIE :: Drools Maven Archetype ...................... FAILURE [  3.405 s]
[INFO] KIE :: Model Archetype ............................. SKIPPED
[INFO] KIE :: KJAR Archetype .............................. SKIPPED
[INFO] KIE :: Service Spring Boot Archetype ............... SKIPPED
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  01:38 min
[INFO] Finished at: 2020-11-12T09:10:02-05:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-archetype-plugin:2.2:integration-test (default-integration-test) on project kie-drools-archetype:
[ERROR] Archetype IT 'integrationtestDefaults' failed: Some content are not equals
[ERROR] Archetype IT 'integrationtestWithCEP' failed: Some content are not equals
[ERROR] Archetype IT 'integrationtestWithEclipse' failed: Some content are not equals
```

However, I don't care about the archetype generation because I am not using that part of this build of the tool (i.e., the files it would generate are already being built by another tool).  How can I remove the goal for or ignore the errors of "integration-test" for this maven plugin?  The pom.file does not mention any goals explicitly nor does it execute the tasks explicitly (which seems required according to [How do I run a maven plugin's integration tests?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54968787/how-do-i-run-a-maven-plugins-integration-tests)).  This is the pom.xml (after the header):

```
  <properties>
    <dollar>$</dollar>
  </properties>

  <build>
    <resources>
      <resource>
        <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
        <filtering>true</filtering>
      </resource>
    </resources>

    <extensions>
      <extension>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.archetype</groupId>
        <artifactId>archetype-packaging</artifactId>
        <version>2.2</version>
      </extension>
    </extensions>

    <pluginManagement>
      <plugins>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-archetype-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.2</version>
        </plugin>
      </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
  </build>
</project>
```

And the parent pom.xml simple declares this module.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Simple solution:

```
  <properties>
    <archetype.test.skip>true</archetype.test.skip>
  </properties>
```

Note that this skipping is different than skipping tests or skipping integratio tests (in general).  Both of which have their own cofigurations.